# Javascript fraction subtraction weird behaviour

Tags: javascript

who can tell me why:

```js
console.log(4 - 1)
console.log(4.2 - 1)
console.log(4.01 - 1)
```

But:

```js
console.log(4.1 - 1)
console.log(4.02 - 1)
```

Tried with parseFloat - same issue

Was able to get the desired result with number.toFixed(2).
Still, where is that decimal coming from.

Whats the JS explanation for this?

Comment: This happens because 0.1, in binary, is a tithe. That's why Java and some other languages use some high precision classes, such as `BigDecimal`

Comment: Please see here for a great article on floating point issues and limitations: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado What is the definition of `tithe` in the context of computation?

Comment: @Amy - maybe I mistranslated what I mean by tithe. Here is the definition from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicContinuedFraction.html): _A periodic continued fraction is a continued fraction (generally a regular continued fraction) whose terms eventually repeat from some point onwards._

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Ah, that makes sense then.  In English, a "tithe" is 1/10th of your earnings paid to a church as tribute.  I'm not aware of any other definitions.  Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Amy - Thanks, it was a great read. Had No idea.

Comment: @Amy Bad Google Translator XD... Thanks for the information